Yucca elephantipes leaves drying
My yucca’s leaves are browning and drying out in the middle. I have had it for 5 years. I repotted this spring. In summer I water every 1-2 weeks when soil is dry and about 1x month in winter. It gets south facing light and I rotate it every few months. Could rotating it be the problem? This is my favorite plant, help!!





Firstly, I can tell just by looking that this isn't a yucca - more likely, it's a species of Dracaena. The most probable causes, to me, seem to be disease or underwatering - I would personally give it a light water whenever the soil looks dry. In case the damage is fungal I would remove and dispose of all dead and dying leaves to prevent it from spreading.
